# Returns a pointer to member variable?

Tags: c++

I tried to implement encapsulation for my linked list node class, but it seems that I did something wrong. How can I make a function return a pointer to a member variable inside class?

```
template <typename T>
class DoublyLinkListNode
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using size_type = size_t;

    DoublyLinkListNode() :m_value(value_type()), m_prev(nullptr), m_next(nullptr) {}
    DoublyLinkListNode(const_reference p_value) : m_value(p_value), m_prev(nullptr), m_next(nullptr) {}
    DoublyLinkListNode(const_reference p_value, DoublyLinkListNode* p_prev, DoublyLinkListNode* p_next) : m_value(p_value), m_prev(p_prev), m_next(p_next) {}
    DoublyLinkListNode(value_type&& p_value, DoublyLinkListNode* p_prev, DoublyLinkListNode* p_next) : m_value(p_value), m_prev(p_prev), m_next(p_next) { p_value = value_type(); }

    // Dereference that allows us to write/read into Elem.
    reference operator*() { return m_value; }
    const_reference operator*() const { return m_value; }

    DoublyLinkListNode* previous() { return m_prev; }
    //const DoublyLinkListNode* previous() const { return m_prev; }
    DoublyLinkListNode* next() { return m_next; }
    //const DoublyLinkListNode* next() const { return m_next; }

    private:
    DoublyLinkListNode* m_prev; // previous link.
    DoublyLinkListNode* m_next; // succesor (next) link.
    T m_value;
};
int main()
{
    DoublyLinkListNode<double>* node = new DoublyLinkListNode(5.5);
    DoublyLinkListNode<double> node2(5.5);
    DoublyLinkListNode<double>* node3 = new DoublyLinkListNode(5.5);

    // expression must be a modifiable lvalue?
    node->previous() = node3;

    std::cout << node->operator*() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `reference` and `const_reference`? Please make a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, I just add a full version for it.

Comment: `previous` and `next` need to return the pointers by reference to allow for assignment. However, if you're going to do that, why not just make the members public?

Comment: I just wants to follow encapsulation by OOP.

Comment: In that case, what you're trying to do in `main` doesn't seem right. Only the class should be able to modify the prev and next pointers. Allowing other parts of the program to do that breaks the encapsulation.

Comment: I really don't catch it. @cigien Can you tweak my code?

Comment: `node->previous() = node3` looks, smells and tastes exactly like `str.size() = 42`.

Comment: Do `DoublyLinkListNode*& previous() { return m_prev; }` if you really want to. But like I said, that's *not* a good idea.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But it returns DoublyLinkListNode*  so I think it should be assignable?

Comment: "str.size() returns an integer so it should be assignable".

Comment: Anyway, if you want it to be assignable, just male `m_prev` public. Same result but less  hassle.

Comment: Thanks, you all. You've helped me have a well sleep night.

Comment: Your function does not attempt to return a [pointer to member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members). Rather, it attempts to return a member that is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

*"How can I make a function return a pointer to a member variable inside class?"*

You're talking about `m_prev`. The type of `m_prev` is `DoublyLinkListNode*`. A pointer to this variable has type `DoublyLinkListNode**`. The function would have to return `DoublyLinkListNode**`:

```
DoublyLinkListNode** previous() { return &m_prev; }
```

and you could use it as

```
*(node->previous()) = node3;
```

But the C++ way is return a reference instead of a pointer:

```
DoublyLinkListNode*& previous() { return m_prev; }
```

and you can use it as

```
node->previous() = node3;
```

The current implementation

```
DoublyLinkListNode* previous() { return m_prev; }
```

returns a temporary copy (R-value).

But instead of a getter and setter or a function that returns a pointer/reference you should make the members public: [C.131: Avoid trivial getters and setters](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-get)